# Host for Lift Projects

Tags: scala, jakarta-ee, hosting, lift, host

Where can I host projects that are built using Scala/Lift? I am working on a prototype and would like to move my code to a host where I can show progress to my client. I was able to use Dropbox to share the project when I had pure HTML5/CSS, but now the project has Scala/Lift implemented.

Answer (score 4):

I have a Lift/Scala app hosted via Dotcloud.com which has been great so far and very low lock in because it is on EC2.

Also, App Engine can only use part of Lift's feature set (unless then removed the single-thread restriction).  I know there is a demo of it running but it cannot use Actors which was a deal breaker for me.

Answer (score 3):

I used cloudbees (http://www.cloudbees.com/run-pricing.cb, they have a small free ) in combination with the sbt-cloudbees plugin (https://github.com/timperrett/sbt-cloudbees-plugin).

After the configuration

```
resolvers += "sonatype.repo" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public"
addSbtPlugin("eu.getintheloop" %% "sbt-cloudbees-plugin" % "0.4.0-SNAPSHOT")

seq(cloudBeesSettings :_*)
CloudBees.apiKey := Some("FXXXXXXXXXXX")
CloudBees.apiSecret := Some("AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=")
CloudBees.username := Some("youruser")
CloudBees.applicationId := Some("yourapp")
```

you can deploy your app with

```
cloudbees-deploy
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to deploy your application on an OpenShift JBoss AS7 application.  You can actually also deploy it as source and it will be compiled and deployed when you do a git push.  Although there isn't a 'scala' application type, the Scala libraries can be added to your git repository and loaded at application deployment.

Answer (score 1):

Google app engine works as well see http://www.scala-lang.org/node/1831

Comment: as long as you do not use comet and/or ajax

Answer (score 0):

You could use an Amazon EC2 instance.

But there are thousands of hosting companies that could provide you with an environment to host your app.

Answer (score 0):

You can also host your Lift app with [Cloud Foundry](http://www.cloudfoundry.com/) or [OpenShift](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/)